# Unpinning Cloth Deforms Object

Tags: modeling, animation, modifiers, physics, cloth-simulation

I have a plane for which I've enabled the cloth modifier. I have pinned the four corners of the plane to empty objects. I've animated the empty objects to move the plane down and collide with a sphere. (This is all made clear by the video)

I want to unpin the plane once it has collided with the sphere, so I added a vertex weight edit modifier to the plane. This allows me to remove the pinned vertex group when the plane collides.

Everything works as expected except that when the pinned vertex group is removed, the plane remains deformed as if it were still being tugged. In other words, when the plane is unpinned, it doesn't return to its original shape like a real elastic piece of cloth. Is there any way to achieve this? I've attached the blender file below and am using the latest version of blender (2.8).

[Video](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1098coq8MePLjxcbdeAUTu1nELT9OoX53)

[Blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gt6JShU_NlrAH9lae7E1dqa0sctWSg86/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: When uploading .blend files, upload to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to ensure that your file stays around, as links expire over time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disabling Group on the way (of running simulation) is like to change the rules of game in a middle of match (shocked audience).

- Let **Group Remove** enabled
- and animate **Remove Treshold** parameter

by adding first keyframe on a frame were *pin* group should still affect cloth with value 0, second keyframe on a frame were *pin* group should stop affect cloth with value 1.

[image]

[image]